# What are the common English mistakes that native Russian speakers make?

Tags: grammar

I've lived in the US for 10 years.  I've never learned grammar formally and usually rely on intuition to guide me.  What really bothers me as of recently is my tendency to really get stuck on a specific type of grammatical concerns during writing.  I have no knowledge of the formal term for this class of mistakes.

Can someone point out to me the common mistakes us Russians make?  Also, what are the proper terms for these mistakes?  Is there a good book or an exercise set to learn from?

[This is a sample of my writing](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1RYhzPacD4u4NsdxnyHUjdIAI2zesnjTOnL2Tke4zI9Y/edit?hl=en_US).

Comment: I've worked with many Russians and in my experience, by far the most common problem is the correct use of the definite and indefinite article.

Comment: @Fraser Orr: Exactly. OP's last sentence in the link *(take the matters in their own hands)*, for example, should properly be *take matters into...* And then there are all those jokes of the form *In Soviet Russia, television watches* **you**, where we'd normally include *"the"* (the omission makes it sound like "mock-Russian speech).

Comment: ...nevertheless, I'm voting to close because this looks too much like a generic "proofreading" request.

Comment: [In Soviet Russia, Trope Mocks You](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/InSovietRussiaTropeMocksYou)